# sql always return the same data

Tags: android, sqlite

In my project, I use SQL (SQLite since its android) to save my data.

I encountered some odd problem:

In my application, I have three tabs and in order to know which data belong to which tab I have in my chart a column for each tab. the number in the column (Integer) represent if and how many of that data suppose to be in this tab.
So, when the tab initialized, it reads from the chart, and using the relevant column, it can tell which data needs to be read and how many.

When I retrieve data from the server (the database of the server is not related to the problem at hand), I check if the data is new or that I already have a similar one in my SQL DB. If its new, I add it to the SQL chart and put 1 in the relevant column. If it already exists, it checks if the data in the SQL is updated (it update the data if necessary) and add 1 to the relevant column (the same column it puts 1 in it in case the data is not in the SQL DB).

**now here's my problem:**
when it reads from the SQL DB to see the number in the column, so it can add 1 to it and then update the chart, **it always return 1** regardless the actual number that in the column in that moment (I know its not really 1 because when I read from the DB in the same column from other places in my app it does read the actual number).

Since in other places in my app it doesn't happen I tried to see what is the difference between the places but I did not find anything wrong (the only difference is that I used WritableDatabase instead of just ReadableDatabase in that time but that should not be an issue as far as I know, at least not in such case).

the code where the problem occurs (the problem is with COL_CART):

```
writable = db.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = writable.query(
                        ShopContract.ShopChart.TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_NAME, ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PRICE, ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PIC, ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_CART},
                        ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PROD_ID + " = '" + product.getProd_id() +"'",
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    //check if the data match, if not, replace.
    if(!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_NAME)).equals(product.getName())){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_NAME,product.getName());
        update(values);
    }
    if(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PRICE)) != product.getPrice()){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PRICE,product.getPrice());
        update(values);
    }
    if(!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PIC)).equals(product.getPicture())){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PIC,product.getPicture());
        update(values);
    }

    //check how many there are already in cart (already in the cursor) and update it to be ++
    Log.d(TAG, "run: the number in col_cart is: " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_CART)));
    int inCart = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_CART)) + 1; // because of the new product we just added
    Log.d(TAG, "run: inCart = " + inCart);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_CART,inCart);
    Log.d(TAG, "run: change cart");
    update(values);
```

edit:
here is the update method code (the writable is being initialized in the code above):

```js
private SQLiteDatabase writable;

            private void update(ContentValues values){
                writable.update(ShopContract.ShopChart.TABLE_NAME, values, ShopContract.ShopChart.COL_PROD_ID + " = '" + product.getProd_id() +"'",null);
            }
```

Comment: show us the update method, and try using Facebook's [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) to see if your database has the correct data or not